# Python try except block does not recognize error type

Tags: python

My scrpt has the following line:

```
libro_dia = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents = libro_dia)
```

When `libro_dia` is not valid, it raises the following error:

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '<!DOCTYP'
```

I whant to handle this error, so I write:

```
try:
    libro_dia = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents = libro_dia)
except XLRDError:
    no_termina = False
```

But it raises the following error:

```
NameError: name 'XLRDError' is not defined
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't have XLRDError imported. I'm not familiar with xlrd, but something like:

```
from xlrd import XLRDError
```

might work. Alternatively, qualify your `Error` when handling it:

```
try:
    libro_dia = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents = libro_dia)
except xlrd.XLRDError: #<-- Qualified error here
    no_termina = False
```

The above is assuming you have the following import:

```
import xlrd
```

---

In response to your comment:

There are several ways to use imports in python. If you import by using `import xlrd`, then you will have to qualify every object in that module as xlrd.SomeObject. An alternative way is by using the form `from xlrd import *`, which would allow you to reference the XLRD error without its' module namespace. This is lazy and a bad idea though, as it can lead to namespace clashes. If you would like to reference the error without qualifying it, the correct way to do it would be `from xlrd import XLRDError`, which would allow you to say `except XLRDError`. Read more about [Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: It worked, thanks. So I must import `xlrd` _and_ `XLRDError` from `xlrd`

Comment: Ah, OK, so if I write `except: xlrd.XLRDError` it also works and I don't need to `import XLRDError from xlrd` first. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`XLRDError` is a custom exception and must be imported to your namespace just like any other object.

Edit: As Burhan Khalid has noted, you could just modify the except block to `except xlrd.XLRDError` if you already have `import xlrd` in your module.

Comment: You should expand your answer to include the solution, which is `xlrd.XLRDError` instead of `XLRDError` in the `except` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 xlrd.XLRDError as e and e.message should contain the error string
```

Sample:

```
   try:
            workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(sys.argv[1])
   except xlrd.XLRDError as e:
            print e.message
            sys.exit(-1)
```